# How to scroll Firefox and IE in WatiN?

Tags: .net, watin

How to scroll Firefox and IE in WatiN?

Comment: Focus an element that's below the fold?

Comment: No. I need position in pixels. Maybe anybody know how get position of DOM Element?

Answer (score 10):

You can call the "scrollIntoView" method for either Internet Explorer or FireFox for any given element using the following code:

For Internet Explorer:

```cs
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{
    var textField = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q"));
    var nativeElement = textField.NativeElement as IEElement;
    nativeElement.AsHtmlElement.scrollIntoView();
}
```

For FireFox:

```cs
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{
    var textField = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q"));
    var nativeElement = textField.NativeElement as JSElement;
    nativeElement.ExecuteMethod("scrollIntoView");
}
```

Likewise, if you want the position of the element, you can use the same code, but instead of calling scrollIntoView(), you can call offsetLeft() and offsetTop() to get the position.

```cs
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{
    var textField = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q"))
    var nativeElement = textField.NativeElement as IEElement;

    int leftoffset = nativeElement.AsHtmlElement.offsetLeft();
    int topoffset = nativeElement.AsHtmlelement.offsetTop();
}
```

Comment: This work only with IE. With Firefox "var nativeElement = textField.NativeElement as IEElement" return null. Please, I need example with Firefox.

Comment: I updated the example to include the FireFox version of autoscrolling to an element.